# Subtracting no of days with system date and converting to MMDDYYYY format in perl

Tags: perl

Input : 45 days
This should be converted to system_date-45= MMDDYYYY format using perl

**Update:**

Code copied in from comment.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
print strftime "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S/n", localtime() - 24 * 60 * 60;
```

Comment: use POSIX 'strftime';
print strftime "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S/n", localtime() - 24 * 60 * 60;

Comment: @MufariaRazak Edit your question to include that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close to closing this question as you didn't include your workings. But I've seen your comment - you should edit your question to include that.

So here's your code:

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
print strftime "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S/n", localtime() - 24 * 60 * 60);
```

That's pretty close. You have three small issues.

1. You have `/n` where you meant `\n`.
2. You have `24 * 60 * 60`, which is one day. You wanted `45 *24 * 60 * 60`.
3. You need to pass subtract the 45 days from the output from `time()` and then pass that value to `localtime()`.

So using your method, you would want:

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
print strftime "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S\n", localtime(time - 45 * 24 * 60 * 60;
```

But I'd write it using [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) (both of which have been part of the Perl code since 5.10.

```
use 5.010; # for say()
use Time::Seconds;
use Time::Piece

say localtime(time - 45 * ONE_DAY)->strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S");'
```

**Update:** If you're going to be running this in the hours around a DST changeover, then you're going to get the wrong answer. The usual approach to fixing this is to normalise the localtime to noon before doing the subtraction.

Comment: Not all days have 24 hours. All of your solutions sometimes return an incorrect answer. (I think it is possible to write a working Time::Piece solution, but I'm not going to try because it's such an awful module.)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many edge cases around daylight saving time that I would *strongly* recommend using a proper date-time library. I would also strongly recommend you use the standard YYYY-MM-DD format: it is unambiguous (is 01022015 Jan2 or Feb1?) and it sorts properly lexically.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E '
    say DateTime->now
                ->set_time_zone("local")
                ->subtract(days => 45)
                ->strftime("%F")
'
2015-10-18
```

Comment: What benefit do you think that DateTIme has over Time::Piece which is already part of the standard Perl distribution?

Comment: It does not assume that every day has 86400 seconds.

Comment: generally, when subtracting a number of days, it does not really matter what time it is. However, some timezones make it really difficult. For example,  in Brazil, where the clock changes at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux system you can try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $date=`date +%m%d%Y -d "45 day ago"`; # This will work only on **linux**
print $date;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use time2str from Date::Format
(86400 is the number of seconds in a day)

`use Date::Format;
print time2str("%m%d%Y",time()-45*86400),"\n";`

Comment: But why, when POSIX::strftime and Time::Piece are both already included with the Perl code?

Comment: Not all days have 24 hours. Your solutions sometimes return an incorrect answer.